# thead tr > * meaning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is meaning of `thead tr > *` and `tfoot tr > *`  in find method of jquery in following code :

```
function setParent() {
                var parent = $(settings.parent);
                var table  = $(settings.table);

                parent.append(table);
                parent
                    .css({
                        'overflow-x': 'auto',
                        'overflow-y': 'auto'
                    });

                parent.scroll(function () {
                    var scrollWidth  = parent[0].scrollWidth;
                    var clientWidth  = parent[0].clientWidth;
                    var scrollHeight = parent[0].scrollHeight;
                    var clientHeight = parent[0].clientHeight;
                    var top          = parent.scrollTop();
                    var left         = parent.scrollLeft();

                    if (settings.head)
                        this.find("thead tr > *").css("top", top);

                    if (settings.foot)
                        this.find("tfoot tr > *").css("bottom", scrollHeight - clientHeight - top);

                    if (settings.left > 0)
                        settings.leftColumns.css("left", left);

                    if (settings.right > 0)
                        settings.rightColumns.css("right", scrollWidth - clientWidth - left);
                }.bind(table));
            }
```

If anybody has information, please explain it to me.

Comment: Look up CSS selectors

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/  https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tr>* means all child html that is present inside tr.
  it will not limit to td.

- includes all html controls and tags.

Answer (score 1):

It means all the elements DIRECTLY inside a TR tag. This means in this example:

```
<tr>
     <td>
          <bla>
```

`td` will be applied by this rule but `bla` won't because it's not directly inside the `tr`.

Comment: Actually not, only the next level of elements.

Answer (score 1):

It's all first level children of `tr`

```
<tr>
    <div>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <i></i>
    </div>
</tr>
```

Only `divs` will be selected, not `span` and `i`